# If $a_n$ is a sequence such that the sequence $a_{n+2}$ is convergent, does this mean that $a_n$ must also be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is a sequence such that the sequence $a_{n+2}$ is convergent, does this mean that $a_n$ must also be convergent?

Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence such that the sequence $a_{2n}$ is convergent. Must $a_n$ also be convergent?

---

I do not know how to even approach these two questions, but I am guessing that it might have something to do with [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) since that particular theorem was simply "given" to me to help me prove that some series are convergent and that their limits exist.

Any help and/or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first is yes, because all but finitely many terms of $a_n$ are in the  sequence $a_{n+2}$.  The second is no, for example my sequence could be $0101010101010101...$.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a_n$ is convergent then for any fixed $k$, so it $a_{n+k}$. This is
fairly straightforward to verify from the definition.

For the other, take the sequence
$a_1=1, a_2 = 0, a_3 = 3, a_4 = 0, a_5 = 5, a_6 = 0, ....$.
then $a_{2n} = 0 \to 0$ but clearly the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the first part. I reread the definition of sequence and it does indeed make a lot of sense. In regards to the second part, I am stiff confused. I apologize, but would you please be able to clarify it for me?

Comment: It is an example of a sequence that does not converge but the even terms do.

Comment: Do you know any convergent sequence? Take its terms and put them in even positions; then $a_{2n}$ would converge. Now what does this tell you about the odd terms? Nothing. They can be made anything. Do you know any _obviously_ divergent sequence? Take its terms and put them in odd positions.